# Index out of range when making XMLHttpRequest call

Tags: qt, xmlhttprequest, qml

I'm facing an error I don't really understand.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://..........";
http.open("GET", url, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("readyState=" + http.readyState);
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        if (http.status == 200) {
            console.log("ok");
        } else {
            console.log("not ok");
        }
    }
}
http.send();
```

QtCreator console log:

> qml: readyState=2
>   qml: readyState=3
>   ASSERT failure in QList::at: "index out of range", file C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 510

In Wireshark, the request is made as expected and the page correctly downloaded. What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

I am trying to use same networkaccessmanager in C++ and QML.
I have a Login class to make a connection to a website. The I need to use the same manager to make other requests in QML.
I first thought the problem was about pointer or the way I call Login(), but with Wireshark, the login request and the one made via QML have the same session id. I deduced the problem was not that, but i'm probably wrong.

main.cpp

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
.....
QNetworkAccessManager *networkmanager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
networkmanager = engine.networkAccessManager();

Login login(networkmanager);
```

login.h

```
.....
class Login : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Login(QNetworkAccessManager *manager, QObject *parent = 0);
.....
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *m_manager;
.....
}
```

login.cpp

```
.....
Login::Login(QNetworkAccessManager *manager, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_manager = manager;
    connect(m_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}
.....
```

Comment: Please, post [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Probably the error occurs in another part of program.

Comment: I concur. If you can see the request execute correctly in wireshark, then it's probably blowing up somewhere else. Does the snippet you posted above include line 510?

Comment: Your example is not complete. Show `Login::slotRequestFinished`. And you have memory leak in `main.cpp`.

Comment: Ok, I understood the issue. Login::slotRequestFinished was called from QML because the accessmanager was still connected to this slot. I made a disconnect and everything works fine now.

Meefte, could you please explain me where is this memory leak?